# How can I force my assets to recompile when using the Moovweb SDK?

Tags: css, sass, assets, moovweb

I have a local server running and I'm making changes to the .scss files in the stylesheets directory. I'm doing a hard-refresh in my browser, but my changes aren't showing up.

I know Moovweb uses Sass - so CSS stylesheets are compiled. Is there any way I can **force** the Moovweb SDK to regenerate the CSS files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSS files generated by the Moovweb SDK are in the `assets/stylesheets/.css` folder.

This is a hidden folder btw, so to view it, type:

```
$> ls -a
.  ..  .css  globals  main.scss  pages  sections
```

You can force the regeneration of CSS files by deleting this `.css` folder.

```
$> rm -rf .css/
```

---

You really shouldn't need to do this though. The Sass compiler typically makes sure the `.css` folder is up-to-date.